# How to pass a model between reactive functions in R Shiny?

Tags: shiny

I'm new to R Shiny, so please bear with me. I'm trying to create an interactive model, which works something like this:

1. The user sets some parameters using a slider/push buttons and hits "button1". That generates the model.
2. User can then select some inputs and push "button2" to get predictions based on the model they just generated.

Ideally, it would look something like this:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

observeEvent(input$button1, {
# generate the model, model <- lm(...)
# pass general information about the model to the UI (R's "summary")
})

observeEvent(input$button2, {
# create predictions using model and output them to the UI
})

}
```

But of course model goes out of scope and can't be used in the second observeEvent. I'm just trying to figure out how to get around this, and I can't seem to find an answer.

Comment: Sounds like you need `eventReactive`

Comment: You can use a global variable. See http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, instead of `observeEvent`, try making your model a reactive function:

```
model <- eventReactive(input$button1, {
  # generate the model, tempvariable <- lm(...)
  # pass general information about the model to the UI (R's "summary")
  # Put the model in the last line so that it becomes the return value of the reactive function
  tempvariable
})

observeEvent(input$button2, {
  # create predictions using model and output them to the UI
  # here you can refer to the model by calling it model(),
  # e.g., anova(model()) or temp <- model(), anova(temp)
})
```

Comment: I guess my issue is that I was trying to be clever and adjust some of the user inputs for the model based on the model parameters (eg., range of values that can be input is based on ranges in the training set). eventReactive doesn't execute the "create a slider with adjusted input ranges" functions inside it until it's called, which was leaving me with a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem.